# How to configure Entity Framework Code First collections with strings as foreign keys to parent IDs to cascade delete?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

How can Entity Framework Code First models be configured so collections with strings as IDs/foreign keys cascadingly delete when parents are deleted?

Geofence => Collections doesn't contain `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` in the generated code. Vehicles => Trips, on the other hand, contains `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)`. The only pertinent difference is that Vehicles' ID is an int, while Geofence's ID is a string.

```
public class Geofence
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "coordinates")]
    [Required]
    public List<Coordinate> Coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Coordinate
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string GeofenceID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="lat")]
    [Required]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lng")]
    [Required]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

 public class Vehicle
 {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string VehicleName { get; set; }

    public List<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
 }

  public class Trip
 {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }

    public bool InProgress { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
 }
```

Generates the configuration code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("VTWeb.Models.Coordinate", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("VTWeb.Models.Geofence")
                    .WithMany("Coordinates")
                    .HasForeignKey("GeofenceID");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("VTWeb.Models.VehicleViewModels.Trip", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("VTWeb.Models.VehicleViewModels.Vehicle")
                    .WithMany("Trips")
                    .HasForeignKey("VehicleID")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only pertinent difference is that Vehicles' ID is an int, while Geofence's ID is a string

This is quite significant difference, because `string` is a reference type, hence is nullable by default. Thus, without additional configuration the relationship  is considered [*optional*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#required-and-optional-relationships), and the default delete behavior of optional relationships is to *not* cascade.

There are several ways you can configure the cascade delete, with the most obvious being the fluent API. However, the simplest is to make the relationship *required*. The only thing you need to know is that `[Required`] attribute has no effect when applied to *collection* navigation property - it has to be applied to either *reference* navigation property or FK property.

In your example, there is no reference navigation property, so it has to be on the FK property:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    // ...
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Required] // <--
    public string GeofenceID { get; set; }
    //..
}
```

Note that applying `[Required]` attribute on value type properties (`int`, `double` like in your example etc.) doesn't hurt, but is redundant since they cannot hold `null` values. For value types the [requiredness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/required-optional) is basically controlled by whether you use nullable type or not. So the main usage of `[Required]` attribute is for `string` and reference navigation properties.

For completeness, or if you want to keep the relationship optional and still have cascade delete, here is the minimal fluent configuration needed:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Geofence>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Coordinates)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```